# Why does this script work in the current directory but fail when placed in the path?

Tags: bash

I wish to replace my failing memory with a very small shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! [ –a $1.sav ]; then
    mv $1 $1.sav
    cp $1.sav $1
fi
nano $1
```

is intended to save the original version of a script. If the original has been preserved before, it skips the move-and-copy-back (and I use move-and-copy-back to preserve the original timestamp).

This works as intended if, after I make it executable with *chmod* I launch it from within the directory where I am editing, e.g. with

```
./safe.sh filename
```

However, when I move it into `/usr/bin` and then I try to run it in a different directory (without the leading `./`) it fails with:

> ```
> *-bash: /usr/bin/safe.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Text file busy*
> ```

My question is, when I move this script into the path (verified by `echo $PATH`) why does it then fail?

D'oh? Inquiring minds want to know how to make this work.

Comment: How did you execute it? Also, did you mark it as executable?

Comment: Well, in /user/bin it is in the path so I just entered 

safe.sh filename


And, yes, I did chmod +x safe.sh to mark it as executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` command is not normally used to run standalone scripts, and that seems to be what is confusing you. `.` is more typically used interactively to add new bindings to your environment (e.g. defining shell functions). It is also used to similar effect within scripts (e.g. to load a script "library").

Once you mark the script executable (per the comments on your question), you should be able to run it equally well from the current directory (e.g. `./safe.sh filename`) or from wherever it is in the path (e.g. `safe.sh filename`).

You may want to remove `.sh` from the name, to fit with the usual conventions of command names.

BTW: I note that you mistakenly capitalize `If` in the script.

Comment: My point is: It is a bad idea to ever try running a command script using `.`, since the semantics are very different.

Comment: Thank you for noting the typo; using a virtual KVM-over-IP rig so I have to shift mental gears between Linux and The Unspeakable OS. I'd caught that on the Linux system when I was pasting that in, but to reach the web, I must use The Unspeakable.

Comment: Does it work without `.` from the current directory?

Comment: That's normal, assuming the current directory isn't in your path. (There's a big difference between `. foo` and `./foo`.)

Comment: Another weird thing: The dash in the script you pasted is an "en dash" and not a regular hyphen.

Comment: Having fixed that issue, near as I can tell the script works for me. I tried on both OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The error `bad interpreter: Text file busy` occurs if the script is open for write (see [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384398/usr-bin-perl-bad-interpreter-text-file-busy/) and [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/21561/bad-interpreter-text-file-busy)). Make sure you don't have it open (e.g. in a editor) when attempting to run it.